# What is the NOP in JVM bytecode used for?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, no-op

Are there any practical uses of the Java Virtual Machine's `NOP` opcode in today's JVM? If so, what are some scenarios in which `NOP`s would be generated in bytecode?

I would even be interested to see an example of Java code that compiles into bytecode with `NOP`s.

---

**Update**

BCEL's [MethodGen](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/MethodGen.html) class says,

> While generating code it may be necessary to insert NOP operations.

I am guessing other Bytecode generation libraries are in the same boat, as was pointed out in the accepted answer.

Comment: Usually it is used in debug code to allow breakpoints on something that doesn't translate into bytecode, like `{`.

Comment: Do you mean this would appear in bytecode when a Java file is compiled with `javac -g`?

Comment: I don't believe `javac` will do that. But other compilers and debuggers could make use of that functionality.

Comment: As an example, using soot to generate Jimple code with some if statements results in NOPs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some `NOP` bytecode use cases are for `class` file transformations, optimizations and static analysis performed by tools such as [Apache BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/bcel/), [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), etc. The Apache [BCEL manual](https://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html) touches on some uses of `NOP` for analysis and optimization purposes.

A JVM may use `NOP` bytecodes for JIT optimizations to ensure code blocks that are at synchronization safepoints are properly aligned to avoid [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

As for some sample code compiled using the JDK `javac` compiler that contains `NOP` bytecodes, that's an interesting challenge. However, I doubt the compiler will generate any `class` file containing `NOP` bytecodes since [`the bytecode instruction stream is only single-byte aligned`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11). I would be curious to see such an example, but I can't think of any myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from some code I've been working on where nop instructions
where placed into the byte code (as viewed by Bytecode Visualizer for Eclipse)

The original code

```
public abstract class Wrapper<T extends Wrapper<T,E>,E>
  implements Supplier<Optional<E>>, Consumer<E>
{
  /** The wrapped object. */
  protected Optional<E> inner;

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
   */
  /**
   * A basic equals method that will compare the wrapped object to
   * whatever you throw at it, whether it is wrapped or not.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object that)
  {
    return this==that
        ||LambdaUtils.castAndMap(that,Wrapper.class,afterCast
            -> inner.equals(afterCast.inner))
        .orElseGet(()
            -> LambdaUtils.castAndMap(that,Optional.class,afterCast
                -> inner.equals(afterCast))
            .orElseGet(()
                -> Optional.ofNullable(that).map(thatobj
                    -> that.equals(inner.get()))
                .orElseGet(()
                    -> false)));
  }
}
```

The translated byte code for the equals(Object) method

```
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object arg0) {
    /* L27 */
    0 aload_0;                /* this */
    1 aload_1;                /* that */
    2 if_acmpeq 36;
    /* L28 */
    5 aload_1;                /* that */
    6 ldc 1;
    8 aload_0;                /* this */
    9 invokedynamic 29;       /* java.util.function.Function apply(ext.cat.wcutils.collections.Wrapper arg0) */
    12 nop;
    13 nop;
    14 invokestatic 30;       /* java.util.Optional ext.cat.wcutils.util.LambdaUtils.castAndMap(java.lang.Object arg0, java.lang.Class arg1, java.util.function.Function arg2) */
    /* L30 */
    17 aload_0;               /* this */
    18 aload_1;               /* that */
    19 invokedynamic 39;      /* java.util.function.Supplier get(ext.cat.wcutils.collections.Wrapper arg0, java.lang.Object arg1) */
    22 nop;
    23 nop;
    24 invokevirtual 40;      /* java.lang.Object orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier arg0) */
    27 checkcast 46;          /* java.lang.Boolean */
    30 invokevirtual 48;      /* boolean booleanValue() */
    /* L37 */
    33 ifne 5;
    /* L27 */
    36 iconst_0;
    37 ireturn;
    38 iconst_1;
    39 ireturn;
}
```

I am not sure why those would be inserted. I just hope they don't adversely affect performance.

Comment: There are no `nop`s, it’s just a bug in the Bytecode Visualizer you have used. The `invokedynamic` instruction consists of five bytes, the last two being zero per specification. Apparently, the Bytecode Visualizer doesn’t know that and assumes the `invokedynamic` instruction to have three bytes only and misinterprets the two zero bytes as `nop` instructions. See [JVM Spec invokedynamic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic).

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I'm waiting for an update to Bytecode Visualizer for Eclipse Neon. Maybe we should tell the developer.

Answer (score -1):

No ops are often added for processor pipeline optimizations. I'm not sure of what extent Java currently uses them.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP#NOP_machine_instruction):

> A NOP is most commonly used for timing purposes, to force memory
>   alignment, to prevent hazards, to occupy a branch delay slot, or as a
>   place-holder to be replaced by active instructions later on in program
>   development (or to replace removed instructions when refactoring would
>   be problematic or time-consuming). In some cases, a NOP can have minor
>   side effects; for example, on the Motorola 68000 series of processors,
>   the NOP opcode causes a synchronization of the pipeline.

Comment: This makes sense in a physical machine opcode, but what would be the use of such a thing for a *virtual* machine opcode?

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this question is very specifically about the JVM.